# How to resolve ExecuteMso throwing "ExecuteMso Not found in _CommandBars"

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a workbook (Call this Master Workbook) that is used to export and create another workbook (Call this Generated Workbook).

The Generated Workbook that is being created is used by some members at my workplace that does not have macros enabled. I am attempting to avoid explaining how to enable macros by using registry keys and prompting the Macro Security screen so they can just press Okay to confirm they made the changes.

For some reason, when you open this Generated Workbook (For the first time) and use `ExecuteMso`, It throws the error listed in the title, or just ignores the command because `On Error Resume Next`. When you reset the macro settings, and restart the Generated Workbook (run `ExecuteMso`), the error does not occur and it works as intended.

I am looking for a solution for this Generated Workbook to open as intended the first time around, not the second.

**EDIT:**
The commandbar "MacroSecurity" can not be found for some reason. Using `Application.CommandBars.FindControl(Id:="MacroSecurity")` I have tried this in both the `Workbook_Open` method and `Workbook_Activate`

**EDIT:**

This is the Master Workbook (The workbook used to create new workbooks)

```
Sub ExportNewMonth()

    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
    Dim myFolder As String
    Dim NewName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        NewName = Sheets("ExportNewMonth").Range("A2").value & " " & MonthName(Sheets("ExportNewMonth").Range("A2"), True) & " " & Sheets("ExportNewMonth").Range("B2")
        Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

        With FldrPicker
            .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .InitialFileName = "C:\"
            If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub 'Check if user clicked cancel button
            myFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        End With
        ConfirmExport = MsgBox("Export Path is: " & myFolder & NewName & ".xlsm", vbInformation + vbOKCancel, "Shift Report will be Exported Here")
        
        If ConfirmExport = vbCancel Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        Dim mySheets() As String
        
        'MsgBox MonthDays(CLng(Sheets("ExportNewMonth").Range("A2")))
        
        ReDim Preserve mySheets(2)
        mySheets(0) = "TechDays"
        mySheets(1) = "ExportEmail"
        mySheets(2) = "InternalFloorSheet"
        
        For i = 2 To MonthDays(CLng(Sheets("ExportNewMonth").Range("A2"))) + 1
            'Make room for TechDays & ExportEmail
            ReDim Preserve mySheets(i + 1)
            mySheets(i + 1) = CStr(i - 1)
        Next i
        
        'MsgBox Join(mySheets, ", ")
        
        Sheets(mySheets).Copy
        
        For i = 2 To MonthDays(CLng(Sheets("ExportNewMonth").Range("A2"))) + 1
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(i - 1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Next i
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportEmail").Visible = xlSheetVisible
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TechDays").Visible = xlSheetHidden
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("InternalFloorSheet").Visible = xlSheetHidden
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("A1").value = Worksheets("ExportNewMonth").Range("A2").value & "/1/" & Worksheets("ExportNewMonth").Range("B2").value
        
        
        Dim ExternalLinks As Variant
        Dim x As Long
        'Purpose: To break external links
        ExternalLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
        For x = 1 To UBound(ExternalLinks)
          ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:=ExternalLinks(x), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
        Next x
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportEmail").Buttons("DisableUpdateBtn").OnAction = ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportEmail").CodeName & ".DisableAutoUpdate"
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportEmail").Buttons("EnableUpdateBtn").OnAction = ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportEmail").CodeName & ".EnableAutoUpdate"
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportEmail").Buttons("Export Email Button").OnAction = ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportEmail").CodeName & ".ExportEmail"
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportEmail").Buttons("Update Floor Sheet Button").OnAction = ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportEmail").CodeName & ".UpdateInternalFloorSheet"
        
        ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid GUID:="{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}", Major:=1, Minor:=0 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime
        ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", Major:=1, Minor:=0 'Microsoft VB for Applications Extensibility 5.3
        
        Dim Names As Variant
        
        For Each Names In mySheets
            
            If CStr(Names) <> "TechDays" And CStr(Names) <> "ExportEmail" And CStr(Names) <> "InternalFloorSheet" Then
                'MsgBox Names
                With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportEmail").DropDowns("Day Dropdown")
                    .AddItem Names
                End With
            End If
        
        Next Names
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportEmail").DropDowns("Day Dropdown").value = "1"
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportEmail").Activate
        
        On Error GoTo NoSave
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs myFolder & NewName & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        
        'Add Module1 to Workbook CodeModule
        Dim SourceModule As VBIDE.CodeModule, DestinationModule As VBIDE.CodeModule
        Set SourceModule = Me.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule
        Set DestinationModule = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveWorkbook.CodeName).CodeModule
        With SourceModule
            DestinationModule.AddFromString .Lines(1, .CountOfLines)
        End With
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportNewMonth").Range("A11").Select
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End With
    MsgBox "Worksheet Exported!", vbInformation, "Success"
    Exit Sub
    
NoSave:
    MsgBox "Cannot save File because it already exists.", vbCritical, "Error"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportNewMonth").Range("A11").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Public Function MonthDays(myMonth As Long) As Long
     
    MonthDays = Day(DateSerial(Year(Date), myMonth + 1, 1) - 1)
     
End Function

Public Function WorksheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    WorksheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function

Sub FormatAllSheets()

    For i = 1 To 31
        Dim DaySheet As Worksheet
        Set DaySheet = Sheets(CStr(i))
        'Activate Day Sheet
        DaySheet.Activate
        
        'Shift Summary
        DaySheet.Range("B11:E17,O11:R17,AB11:AE17").WrapText = True
        DaySheet.Range("B11:E17,O11:R17,AB11:AE17").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        DaySheet.Range("B11:E17,O11:R17,AB11:AE17").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        DaySheet.Range("F11:K17,S11:X17,AF11:AK17").WrapText = True
        DaySheet.Range("B19:K22,S19:X22,AF19:AK22").WrapText = True
        
        'CONTINUE THIS STUFF
        'CONTINUE THIS STUFF
        'CONTINUE THIS STUFF
        'CONTINUE THIS STUFF
        'CONTINUE THIS STUFF
        
        
        
        'Set Location to First Cell of Day Sheet
        DaySheet.Range("B11:B11").Select
    Next i

End Sub

Sub CreateDaySheets()
    Dim i As Long
    If WorksheetExists("1") Then
        For i = 2 To 31
            If WorksheetExists(CStr(i)) Then
                ConfirmDelete = MsgBox("Are you sure you would like to delete Sheet """ & CStr(i) & """?", vbInformation + vbYesNo)
                If ConfirmDelete = vbNo Then
                    MsgBox "Error: Can not create sheet that already exists."
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(CStr(i)).Delete
            End If
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(i - 1)).Copy After:=Worksheets(CStr(i - 1))
            ActiveSheet.Name = CStr(i)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Formula = "='" & i - 1 & "'!A1:L1+1"
            ActiveSheet.Range("B11:B11").Select
        Next i
        MsgBox "Complete! All 31 day sheets have now been made and hidden!", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: No base sheet to copy! This macro is used to copy a day sheet 31 times and format the date cells.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call EnableMacroReg
    
    ActiveWindow.TabRatio = 0.73
End Sub

Public Sub EnableMacroReg()

  Dim myWS As Object
  Set myWS = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Dim VBOMReg As String, VBAWarningReg As String, stype As String
  Dim ProtectView1 As String, ProtectView2 As String, ProtectView3 As String
  Dim Changed As Boolean
  
  Changed = False
  
  VBAWarningReg = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\VBAWarnings"
  VBOMReg = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM"
  ProtectView1 = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\ProtectedView\DisableAttachmentsInPV"
  ProtectView2 = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\ProtectedView\DisableInternetFilesInPV"
  ProtectView3 = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\ProtectedView\DisableUnsafeLocationsInPV"
  stype = "REG_DWORD"

  'Edit Macro Registry for VBAWarningValue
  On Error Resume Next
    VBAWarningValue = myWS.RegRead(VBAWarningReg)
    bFound = (Err.Number = 0)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If bFound Then
    If (VBAWarningValue <> 1) Then
      myWS.RegWrite VBAWarningReg, 1, stype
      Changed = True
    End If
  Else
    myWS.RegWrite VBAWarningReg, 1, stype
    Changed = True
  End If
  
  'Edit Macro Registry for ProtectedView1
  On Error Resume Next
    ProtectView1Value = myWS.RegRead(ProtectView1)
    bFound = (Err.Number = 0)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If bFound Then
    If (ProtectView1Value <> 1) Then
      myWS.RegWrite ProtectView1, 1, stype
      Changed = True
    End If
  Else
    myWS.RegWrite ProtectView1, 1, stype
    Changed = True
  End If
  
  'Edit Macro Registry for ProtectedView2
  On Error Resume Next
    ProtectView2Value = myWS.RegRead(ProtectView2)
    bFound = (Err.Number = 0)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If bFound Then
    If (ProtectView2Value <> 1) Then
      myWS.RegWrite ProtectView2, 1, stype
      Changed = True
    End If
  Else
    myWS.RegWrite ProtectView2, 1, stype
    Changed = True
  End If
  
  'Edit Macro Registry for ProtectedView3
  On Error Resume Next
    ProtectView3Value = myWS.RegRead(ProtectView3)
    bFound = (Err.Number = 0)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If bFound Then
    If (ProtectView3Value <> 1) Then
      myWS.RegWrite ProtectView3, 1, stype
      Changed = True
    End If
  Else
    myWS.RegWrite ProtectView3, 1, stype
    Changed = True
  End If
  
  'Edit Macro Registry for VBOMValue
  On Error Resume Next
    VBOMValue = myWS.RegRead(VBOMReg)
    bFound = (Err.Number = 0)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If bFound Then
    If (VBOMValue <> 1) Then
      myWS.RegWrite VBOMReg, 1, stype
    End If
  Else
    myWS.RegWrite VBOMReg, 1, stype
    Changed = True
  End If

  If Changed Then
    msg = MsgBox("Macro Settings have now been installed. Excel will now restart." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please press Okay on the next prompt to ensure settings are set!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Macro-Enabling")
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MacroSecurity"
    On Error GoTo 0
  
    Application.Quit
  End If

End Sub
```

*This is the Module, that gets added to the New Generated Workbook.*

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim LocRanges, AssetRanges, ARHRanges As Range
    Dim IFSheet As Worksheet
    Dim FoundItem As Range
    Dim FIRow As Long
    Dim AssetVRange, CabinetVRange, ThemeVRange As Range
    Set LocRanges = Sh.Range("B11:B17,O11:O17,AB11:AB17,B27:B29,O27:O29,AB27:AB29,B34:B36,O34:O36,AB34:AB36,B41:B43,O41:O43,AB41:AB43,B48:B50,O48:O50,AB48:AB50,B55:B57,O55:O57,AB55:AB57,F27:F29,S27:S29,AF27:AF29")
    Set AssetRanges = Sh.Range("C11:C17,P11:P17,AC11:AC17,C27:C29,P27:P29,AC27:AC29,C34:C36,P34:P36,AC34:AC36,C41:C43,P41:P43,AC41:AC43,C48:C50,P48:P50,AC48:AC50,C55:C57,P55:P57,AC55:AC57,G27:G29,T27:T29,AG27:AG29")
    Set ARHRanges = Sh.Range("F11:F17,B19:B22,D27:D29,H27:H29,G34:G39,F41:F43,F48:F50,E55:E57,G55:G57,S11:S17,O19:O22,Q27:Q29,U27:U29,T34:T39,S41:S43,S48:S50,R55:R57,T55:T57,AF11:AF17,AB19:AB22,AD27:AD29,AH27:AH29,AG34:AG39,AF41:AF43,AF48:AF50,AE55:AE57,AG55:AG57")
    Set IFSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("InternalFloorSheet")
    
    'Disable Events so this doesn't trigger again
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    'AutoRowHeight Feature '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Not Intersect(ARHRanges, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Target.EntireRow.AutoFit
    End If
    
    'If more than one cell is changed/targeted, ignore
    If Target.Count > 1 Then
        Call CheckEvents
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'If the target cell was cleared, or left empty, ignore
    If Target.value = "" Then
        Call CheckEvents
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'If the target/changed cell was pasted, ignore
    Dim o As CommandBarComboBox
    Set o = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo")
    If o.Enabled = True Then
        If o.ListCount >= 1 Then
            If o.List(1) = "Paste" Then
                Call CheckEvents
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    'Auto Update Feature''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Not Intersect(LocRanges, Target) Is Nothing Then
        'Change occurs in Location Field
        Set FoundItem = IFSheet.Range("B:B").Find(What:=Target.value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not FoundItem Is Nothing Then
            If FoundItem.value = "" Then
                Call CheckEvents
                Exit Sub
            End If
            FIRow = FoundItem.Row
            Set AssetVRange = IFSheet.Range(Cells(FIRow, 1).Address)
            Set CabinetVRange = IFSheet.Range(Cells(FIRow, 7).Address)
            Set ThemeVRange = IFSheet.Range(Cells(FIRow, 6).Address)
            Sh.Range(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Address).value = AssetVRange.value
            If Not (Target.Row >= 27 And Target.Row <= 29) Then
                Sh.Range(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 2).Address).value = CabinetVRange.value
                If Not (Target.Row >= 55 And Target.Row <= 57) Then
                    Sh.Range(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 3).Address).value = ThemeVRange.value
                End If
            End If
            Call CheckEvents
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Call CheckEvents
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
    ElseIf Not Intersect(AssetRanges, Target) Is Nothing Then
        'Change occurs in Asset Field
        Set FoundItem = IFSheet.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Target.value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not FoundItem Is Nothing Then
            If FoundItem.value = "" Then
                Call CheckEvents
                Exit Sub
            End If
            FIRow = FoundItem.Row
            Set LocVRange = IFSheet.Range(Cells(FIRow, 2).Address)
            Set CabinetVRange = IFSheet.Range(Cells(FIRow, 7).Address)
            Set ThemeVRange = IFSheet.Range(Cells(FIRow, 6).Address)
            
            Sh.Range(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1).Address).value = LocVRange.value
            If Not (Target.Row >= 27 And Target.Row <= 29) Then
                Sh.Range(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Address).value = CabinetVRange.value
                If Not (Target.Row >= 55 And Target.Row <= 57) Then
                    Sh.Range(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 2).Address).value = ThemeVRange.value
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Call CheckEvents
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Call CheckEvents
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Call CheckEvents
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call EnableMacroReg
    
    ActiveWindow.TabRatio = 0.73
    Call CheckEvents
    Call ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExportEmail").UpdateInternalFloorSheet
End Sub

Public Sub EnableMacroReg()

  Dim myWS As Object
  Set myWS = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Dim VBOMReg As String, VBAWarningReg As String, stype As String
  Dim ProtectView1 As String, ProtectView2 As String, ProtectView3 As String
  Dim Changed As Boolean
  
  Changed = False
  
  VBAWarningReg = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\VBAWarnings"
  VBOMReg = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM"
  ProtectView1 = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\ProtectedView\DisableAttachmentsInPV"
  ProtectView2 = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\ProtectedView\DisableInternetFilesInPV"
  ProtectView3 = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\ProtectedView\DisableUnsafeLocationsInPV"
  stype = "REG_DWORD"

  'Edit Macro Registry for VBAWarningValue
  On Error Resume Next
    VBAWarningValue = myWS.RegRead(VBAWarningReg)
    bFound = (Err.Number = 0)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If bFound Then
    If (VBAWarningValue <> 1) Then
      myWS.RegWrite VBAWarningReg, 1, stype
      Changed = True
    End If
  Else
    myWS.RegWrite VBAWarningReg, 1, stype
    Changed = True
  End If
  
  'Edit Macro Registry for ProtectedView1
  On Error Resume Next
    ProtectView1Value = myWS.RegRead(ProtectView1)
    bFound = (Err.Number = 0)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If bFound Then
    If (ProtectView1Value <> 1) Then
      myWS.RegWrite ProtectView1, 1, stype
      Changed = True
    End If
  Else
    myWS.RegWrite ProtectView1, 1, stype
    Changed = True
  End If
  
  'Edit Macro Registry for ProtectedView2
  On Error Resume Next
    ProtectView2Value = myWS.RegRead(ProtectView2)
    bFound = (Err.Number = 0)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If bFound Then
    If (ProtectView2Value <> 1) Then
      myWS.RegWrite ProtectView2, 1, stype
      Changed = True
    End If
  Else
    myWS.RegWrite ProtectView2, 1, stype
    Changed = True
  End If
  
  'Edit Macro Registry for ProtectedView3
  On Error Resume Next
    ProtectView3Value = myWS.RegRead(ProtectView3)
    bFound = (Err.Number = 0)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If bFound Then
    If (ProtectView3Value <> 1) Then
      myWS.RegWrite ProtectView3, 1, stype
      Changed = True
    End If
  Else
    myWS.RegWrite ProtectView3, 1, stype
    Changed = True
  End If
  
  'Edit Macro Registry for VBOMValue
  On Error Resume Next
    VBOMValue = myWS.RegRead(VBOMReg)
    bFound = (Err.Number = 0)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If bFound Then
    If (VBOMValue <> 1) Then
      myWS.RegWrite VBOMReg, 1, stype
    End If
  Else
    myWS.RegWrite VBOMReg, 1, stype
    Changed = True
  End If

  If Changed Then
    msg = MsgBox("Macro Settings have now been installed. Excel will now restart." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please press Okay on the next prompt to ensure settings are set!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Macro-Enabling")
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MacroSecurity"
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox "Attempted to Open MacroSecurity" & " - Application: " & Application.Name
  
    Application.Quit
  End If

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'Disable Auto Update & Save
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExportEmail").Range("J1").value = "Auto Update: Disabled"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExportEmail").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExportEmail").Range("A1").Select
    Call CheckEvents
    'Save, then check if saved to be sure.
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    If Saved = False Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub CheckEvents()
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExportEmail").Range("J1").value = "Auto Update: Disabled" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExportEmail").Range("J1").value = "Auto Update: Enabled" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExportEmail").Range("J1").value = "Auto Update: Disabled"
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
End Sub
```

*This is a sheet that gets coppied from the Master Workbook, too the Generated Workbook (Call this sheet "ExportEmail")*

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExportEmail()
   Dim appOutlook As Object
   Dim mItem As Object
   Dim appOutlook2 As Object
   Dim mItem2 As Object
   Dim Signature As String
   Dim Shiftdd As DropDown
   Dim Daydd As DropDown
   Dim RangeHTML As Range
   Dim EDropRangeHTML As Range
   Dim EDroppable As Boolean
   Dim wsDay As Worksheet
   
   Set Shiftdd = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportEmail").DropDowns("Shift Dropdown")
   Set Daydd = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportEmail").DropDowns("Day Dropdown")
   Set wsDay = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(Daydd.value))
   Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set mItem = appOutlook.CreateItem(0)
   Set appOutlook2 = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set mItem2 = appOutlook2.CreateItem(0)
   EDroppable = True
   
   With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
   End With
    
    Select Case Shiftdd.List(Shiftdd.ListIndex)
    
    Case "Day Shift"
    Set RangeHTML = wsDay.Range("A1:L62")
    Set EDropRangeHTML = wsDay.Range("B24:K29")
    If IsEmptyRange(wsDay.Range("B27:K29")) Then
        EDroppable = False
    End If
    
    Case "Swing Shift"
    Set RangeHTML = wsDay.Range("N1:Y62")
    Set EDropRangeHTML = wsDay.Range("O24:X29")
    If IsEmptyRange(wsDay.Range("O27:X29")) Then
        EDroppable = False
    End If
    
    Case "Grave Shift"
    Set RangeHTML = wsDay.Range("AA1:AL62")
    Set EDropRangeHTML = wsDay.Range("AB24:AK29")
    If IsEmptyRange(wsDay.Range("AB27:AK29")) Then
        EDroppable = False
    End If
    
    End Select
    
    Dim specificDay As Range
    
    Set specificDay = wsDay.Cells(RangeHTML.Row, RangeHTML.Column)
    
    With Application
     .EnableEvents = True
     .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
   wsDay.Copy
   
   Dim TempWB As Workbook
   Set TempWB = ActiveWorkbook
   
   'Remove VBA Elements
   Dim Element As VBComponent
   Dim LineCount As Integer
   For Each Element In TempWB.VBProject.VBComponents
      LineCount = Element.CodeModule.CountOfLines
      Element.CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, LineCount
   Next
   
   TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=Environ$("temp") & "\Shift Report - " & Format(specificDay.value, "mm-dd-YYYY ") & Format(Now(), "hh-nn-ss AM/PM") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
   'MsgBox TempWB.FullName
   If (EDroppable) Then
    With mItem2
      .Display
      Signature = .HTMLBody
      .To = "xxx"
      .CC = ""
      .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(EDropRangeHTML) & Signature
      .Subject = "E-Drop"
    End With
   End If
   
   With mItem
     .Display
     Signature = .HTMLBody
     .To = "xxx"
     .CC = ""
     .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(RangeHTML) & Signature
     .Subject = "Shift Report - " & Shiftdd.List(Shiftdd.ListIndex) & " - " & specificDay.value
     If Shiftdd.List(Shiftdd.ListIndex) = "Grave Shift" Then
        .Attachments.Add TempWB.FullName
     End If
   End With
   TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
   mItem.Display
   Set TempWB = Nothing
   Set mItem = Nothing
   Set appOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
Sub UpdateInternalFloorSheet()
    'dOES SOME WONKY STUFF
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook


    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"


    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With


    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With


    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")


    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Kill TempFile


    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function

Sub testtest()

    Call IsEmptyRange(ActiveSheet.Range("O27:X29"))

End Sub

Public Function IsEmptyRange(rng As Range) As Boolean
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
        'Empty Range
        IsEmptyRange = True
    Else
        'Contains Text
        IsEmptyRange = False
    End If
End Function

Public Function MonthDays(myMonth As Long) As Long
     
    MonthDays = Day(DateSerial(Year(Date), myMonth + 1, 1) - 1)
     
End Function

Sub EnableAutoUpdate()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExportEmail").Range("J1").value = "Auto Update: Enabled"
End Sub

Sub DisableAutoUpdate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExportEmail").Range("J1").value = "Auto Update: Disabled"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExportEmail").Range("J1").value = "Auto Update: Disabled" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested using ExecuteMso in the Workbook_Open event handler with Excel 365 and did not run into any issues. The dialog popped up as expected when opening the file.

Comment: Maybe it is because I am creating a workbook externally, I will update the question with this code @taller_ExcelHome

Comment: I have noticed the first time this workbook is open, `Application.Quit` also does not seem to work. So maybe Application is struggling to be defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added this as an answer as it is too long for a comment ... however, only your testing this can show if it really answers your question and fixes your problem.

My theory is that the problem could be caused by the `Workbook_Open` event (as, in your code, `Workbook_Open` calls `EnableMacroReg` which contains the problem line) running too early as it is known to sometimes do so before the Excel object model is fully loaded ... this is something I have seen before. There are a couple of possible workarounds:

**1. Auto_Open**

Replace `Workbook_Open` (which will be in your `ThisWorkbook` Module) with `Auto_Open` which must be a Sub in a standard Module. `Auto_Open` runs after `Workbook_Open` (though has the downside that it does not run at all if the Workbook is opened programmatically) eg

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    ' move your code from Workbook_Open to here
End Sub
```

**2. Delay Workbook_Open**

Move the code out of `Workbook_Open` into another Sub in the `ThisWorkbook` Module, maybe called `WorkbookOpenDelayed` (or whatever you want).

Add the following line to `Workbook_Open`:

```
Application.OnTime Now, "'" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'!WorkbookOpenDelayed"
```

This means that `WorkbookOpenDelayed` should only run after all other already-scheduled code is run which should be after Excel is fully loaded and ready.

As I said at the start, I cannot offer a guarantee that this is a solution for your problem but please test and advise.